# Drupal 6: Date module and displaying only DATE value, without TIME

Tags: datetime, drupal, date, time, drupal-6

I'm a newbie drupal guy,

I use http://drupal.org/project/date module for my events date, but this module displays TIME as well as default, and I can't turn that off from configuration pages unless I'm a blind :/ is there any way to display only DATE value?

Appreciate helps!! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a new date and time format that only specifies the date portion under  Administer › Site configuration › Date and time › Formats › Add format (the relative path is /admin/settings/date-time/formats/add).

Here are a couple of popular date formats strings according to the [PHP date format characters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):
`m/d/Y` becomes *06/22/2010*
`l, F j, Y` becomes *Tuesday, June 22, 2010*

You can either set one of the three default format types (i.e. long, medium, or short) to use your custom format or you can add a new format type. In either case, you would just need to specify the date field to use the format type that is set to your custom date format.

Answer (score 0):

See [Display multiple Date formats](http://drupal.org/node/295105), along with [Theme the Date](http://drupal.org/node/123181) and [Example - Theme all-day events without a time](http://drupal.org/node/235662) for more information on this (while the last two links are targeting Drupal 5, they still apply for Drupal 6, AFAIK).